# Unknown Matplotlib error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I get the following error and I cannot work out what or how I should fix it:

```
python-2.7.4_scipy0.13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py:2757: UserWarning: Attempting to set identical bottom==top results
in singular transformations; automatically expanding.
bottom=0, top=0.0
  + 'bottom=%s, top=%s') % (bottom, top))
```

The code is:

```
plt.scatter(chart_dict[chart][0], chart_dict[chart][1], c=colours[count], alpha=1.0, label=chart, lw = 0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.ylabel(titles_markers[2])
plt.xlabel(titles_markers[1])
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='b', linestyle='-')
plt.title(titles_markers[0])
plt.legend()
plt.savefig(os.path.join(directory, titles_markers[0].replace(' ', '_')+'.png'))
```

Comment: The error seems to come from a `scipy0.13` package, which line does the error arise?

Comment: Does it help when you move `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.savefig(...)` ?

Comment: Could you please include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)